# jquery get xx element start in yyy index

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please find this html example code

```
 <ul>
     <li>India</li>
     <li>Indonesia</li>
     <li>China</li>
     <li>United States</li>
     <li>United Kingdom</li>
 </ul>
```

it is possible to get xx li element by yy index ?
For exemple, xx = 2 ( element ) and y = 1 ( index ) gave me

```
<li>Indonesia</li><li>China</li>
```

Thx all !

Comment: [`:eq()` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: what do you mean by x and y here?

Comment: x = element to be returned, y = index of element

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```js
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var x=2;
var y=1;
var limit=x+y;
for (var i = y; i < limit; ++i) {
  console.log(items[i]);
  // do something with items[i], which is a <li> element
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li>India</li>
     <li>Indonesia</li>
     <li>China</li>
     <li>United States</li>
     <li>United Kingdom</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method

```js
var xx = 2;
var yy = 1;

$("li").slice(yy, xx + yy).css("fontStyle", "italic");
$("li").slice(yy, xx + yy).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>India</li>
   <li>Indonesia</li>
   <li>China</li>
   <li>United States</li>
   <li>United Kingdom</li>
</ul>
```